# List of cookie parameter names to identify load balancing mechanism

Tags: cookies

I need to create my own web application security assessment methodology. Within fingerprinting section I have one test case such as "Checking for load balancing". One part of that test case is to inspect various cookies in order to analyze the load balancing mechanism.

As per my knowledge, I am a aware about few of the vendors who provide such load balancing solution such as F5, Cisco, Radware etc.

My question is as follows:

As per my experience of testing various web applications, I am aware of only one coookie parameter name which is BIG-IP.

I want to have any list, or few of the default cookie names by which one can identify that the load balancer is in place. Can anyone provide me such list of cookie parameter names only?

Comment: I'm not sure this will have a definitive answer. On Fortinet Load Balancers, the admin creates the name. I always used "oreo".

Comment: In short, looking for cookie names is not the way to go. There are many other better ways to do this analysis.

Comment: A10 loadbalancers use a "sto-id" cookie by default, though the administrator can technically name the cookie whatever they want.

Comment: Yes there are other ways to test. However this is one of the test cases which I thought to include. Apart from this I am going to use lbd and other KALI linux tools. However to create a methodology for pentest, its a good practice to include every small and big thing. That is why I have asked this question.